# jquery Block UI not rendering button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, salesforce, visualforce

Hi all I ahve a strange problem.

When I do this in my class and bind the variable to my page it works :

```
$j.blockUI({ message: "<h1><br/>Loading Please wait<br/><br/></h1>});
```

But when I do this it stops working :

```
$j.blockUI({ message: "<h1><br/>Loading Please wait<br/><br/></h1><input type="button" value="No" />" });
```

What I am doing wrong??

My platform is Salesforce and visualforce.

** My screen now look like this but in my code i have give a type button but its taking it as text why??

```
string t = '<input type=\'\' button \'\' value=\'\' OK \'\' >JJJJ</input>';
```

[image: MyResult]

Comment: as ' is escape symbol in APEX i cannot use '.

Comment: Got it its \' only !!

Comment: Inputs with type=button do not act like button tags, inputs are meant only to be a self closing elements, therefore you trying to add text to it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes I got it now i use**

```
<button type=\'button\'>Click</button>
```

and it works fine.

**Mark it as answer if it helped any one else..**

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to escape `"` from the input.

**Example**

```
$j.blockUI({ message: "<h1><br/>Loading Please wait<br/><br/></h1><input type='button' value='No' />" });
```

**OR**

```
$j.blockUI({ message: "<h1><br/>Loading Please wait<br/><br/></h1><input type=\"button\" value=\"No\" />" });
```

Comment: Use Dipesh's second example if you can't use single quote.

Comment: $j.blockUI({ message: "<h1><br/>Loading Please wait<br/><br/></h1><input type=\"button\" value=\"No\" />" });

Comment: @user614946 try with `\\` if that does not work then need to google

Comment: NO That didn't too .. Gives me error on Save "no viable alternative at character '\' "